# Homeomorphism between $D^n$ and $[0,1]^n$

Tags: general-topology

I know that $D^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^n$, but how to write down homeomorphism? How to find explicit formula?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to expand along lines: try with the $n=2$ case, before. It can be useful to rotate the square of an angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$, counterclockwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\| v \|_{p}$ denotes the $p$-norm of $v \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$. In particular,

$$ \| v \|_{2} = [ v_{1}^{2} + \cdots + v_{n}^{2} ]^{1/2} \quad \text{and} \quad \| v \|_{\infty} = \max \{ |v_{1}|, \cdots, |v_{n}| \}. $$

Then the following map

$$ F : D^{n} \to [-1, 1]^{n} : v \mapsto \frac{\|v\|_{2}}{\|v\|_{\infty}} v $$

gives the homeomorphism with the inverse

$$ G : [-1, 1]^{n} \to D^{n} : w \mapsto \frac{\|w\|_{\infty}}{\|w\|_{2}} w. $$

(Of course, we set $F(0) = 0 = G(0)$.)

The idea is simple:

$$ D^{n} = \{ \| v \|_{2} \leq 1 \} \quad \text{and}  \quad [-1, 1]^{n} = \{ \| v\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \}. $$

So the map $F$ rescales the vector so that $\| F(v) \|_{\infty} = \| v \|_{2}$. Checking that both $F$ and $G$ are indeed continuous is not theoretically hard, though it may be somewhat cumbersome.

The following graph may help you what is actually going on in $n = 3$. The sphere (above) is mapped into the cube (below) by the mapping $F$. (The seams between the faces of the cube are software artifacts.)

[image]

Comment: Nice. For some reason it's the first time I've seen this map written explicitly, and always assumed that it's going to be a lot more ugly.

Answer (score 0):

First place $I^n$ in the center of your coordinate system using translation $T$. Then define $F:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ as fallows $F(x)=x/\|\partial T(I^n)\cap l(x)\|$, where $l(x)$ is a line passing through $0$ and $x$. Now morphism you looking for is $F\circ T$.